# Running a regression for loop in R, dependent variables: returns, Independent: Betas

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

I am attempting to run fama-macbeth regressions, regressing 550 monthly return observations for a number of portfolios on that portfolios previously calculated estimated factor exposures (so regressing 550 return observations on that portfolios "estimated exposure," to each factor I am considering).

So, for each iteration of my regression, I need to consider a different return observation, regressed on the same value for factor exposures to calculate "return factors,"

My loop is as follows, as you can see, I attempt to use "i," to denote the row number in the case of my "estimated exposure," while also using "i," to denote the column number for my returns. My code is as follows

'''

```
library(sandwich)
library(broom)
library(tibble)
f <- file.choose()
data <- read.csv(f)

x <- dput(data)

BTM2R <- data[i, 3]
BIPR <- data[i, 4]
BInfR <- data[i, 5]
BUnR <- data[i, 6]
BOilR <- data[i, 7]

for (i in 1:63){
  mod <- lm(data = data, data[[i+7]]~BTM2R+BIPR+BInfR+BUnR+BOilR)
  print(mod$coefficients)
}
```

'''

Using data: file:///C:/Users/donal/Downloads/Betas.html

And R returns the following warning "Error in model.frame.default(formula = data[[i]] ~ BTM2R + BIPR + BInfR +  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'BTM2R'),"

Is there a way to run this regression in a loop? To find each portfolios return factors given their factor exposures?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide us with the dataset or atleast a minimal reproducible example dataset. Also, you probably want `data[, i+ 7] ~`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, I've never used dput before but this should hopefully work now

Comment: `dput` is a way to share data. Run `dput(data[1:10, 1:5])` (for the first 10 rows and 5 columns, choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem) and edit the result into your question. It will start with `structure(list(...` and will give us a copy/pasteable version of your data.